# How to generate new ipa file in xcode 8.2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

When I make build file that time showing one error. So please help me how to solve this error after make new build file.

I created developer certificate. I used this Automatic select mode on Xcode. I select Generic iOS Device in Build scheme. I try to many time but I show same error.

I attached My screenshot so please check it and give me response.

[image]

Comment: I run with iphone perfectly But Not working when i make new build file.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the bundle id `com.2048light` is used in another developer account. You need to change the bundle id in your project to something unique across all iOS applications and try again. A common mechanism to solve this issue is to put a company identifier in your bundle id.

For example:

`com.mycompany.2048light`

where you replace `mycompany` with your name or the name of the company you are building the app for.

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen if the computer you are building on does NOT have that certificate and is trying to generate one with a different account (Auto-Provisioning).

For example, you might be using your own personal developers account with bundleID: `com.2048light`.

Then on your company's build machine, you might be using the company account and the same bundleID. You can't do that.

You can either do one of the following:

1. Use the company account to run it on your own personal device.
2. You create a new bundleID for the company and build using that.
3. You copy your personal certificates to the company computer and build with that.

I would suggest doing #1. My company adds our personal devices to their list and makes us a member so we don't have to keep changing the project settings. If you can't do that, then do option #2.